# C# LINQ - IListSource not found [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, xamarin

I don't understand why I am receiving this error. I'm trying to query a local database using LINQ for C# in Xamarin for Visual Studio.

Relevant code:

```
// Query for customers in London.
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;
```

The 'where' line is marked as an error, and if I remove it the 'select' line causes the same error:

> Reference to type 'IListSource' claims it is defined in 'System', but
>   it could not be found

VS's object browser reveals IListSource is contained in System.ComponentModel, which I've included in the file header.

> public interface IListSource
>       Member of System.ComponentModel
>
> Summary: Provides functionality to an object to return a list that can
>   be bound to a data source.
>
> Attributes:
>   [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter,
>   System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"),
>   System.ComponentModel.EditorAttribute("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceListEditor,
>   System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor,
>   System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"),
>   System.ComponentModel.MergablePropertyAttribute(false)]

Here is a description of why LINQ uses IListSource:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546190%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Adding project references to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel.Composition does not seem to have an effect.

Is it possible I'm missing a reference? Might this have something to do with Xamarin Forms specifically?

Please let me know if any other information will help. Any pointers on where to look for possible problems on my end is appreciated!

Comment: to me what you do looks like it should only be system.linq that would be needed, but not sure when its xamarin

Comment: Xamarin version ? Did you try updating to the latest?

Comment: Xamarin   4.2.0.719 (15694b9)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Downloading 4.2.1.58 now...
Xamarin.Android   7.0.1.6 (5a02b03)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   10.2.0.4 (b638977)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Odd, I can not reproduce this issue. Adding your code to a new X.Forms solution in the PCL project gives me `Can not implicitly convert type IEnumarable to IQueryable` error message for the whole Linq statement. But then casting to `IQueryable` by putting the Linq statement in parentheses and adding `.AsQueryable<Customer>()` works as expected. IOW I can not reproduce this issue from the code provided. I am likely missing something though as I have not really worked with `IQueryable` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Query for customers in London.
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
from cust in Customers
where cust.City == "London"
select cust;
```

`Customers` is just the object, you need to specify the database somehow:

`database.Customers`

```
// Query for customers in London.
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
from cust in database.Customers
where cust.City == "London"
select cust;
```